# Textures not loading when importing OBJ with MTL file in Three JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to import an object I exported from Cinema 4D. This is the code:

```
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.load('myobj.mtl', function(materials){
    materials.preload();
    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    loader.setMaterials(materials);

    loader.load('myobj.obj', function(object){
            scene.add(object);
            objs = object;
        }
    );
});
```

The object renders properly but it doesn't show the "textures" (the images).

Any ideas? By the way, when I open the MTL with a text editor, it says in one line:

```
map_Kd texture.jpg
```

And the file is there. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: If you open the browser developer tools, do you see any errors in the console or in the network tab?

Comment: It says "An error happened" a few times but doesn't say anything else...